# can't blur input in ios

Tags: ios, blur, iphone-softkeyboard

I'm building an iPad app using Xcode, Cordova and HTML files.

In testing the HTML on an iPad, I'm not able to blur my input fields by clicking outside them.

Do I need to code the background to blur the input?

I want the blur so I can hide the keyboard.

Unless there's a better solution to hiding it that does not need a blur().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found two code snippets that combine to trigger blur on inputs when clicking anywhere outside the input, or when pressing the Return key.

```
function isTextInput(node) {
    return ['INPUT'].indexOf(node.nodeName) !== -1;
}
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    if (!isTextInput(e.target) && isTextInput(document.activeElement)) {
    document.activeElement.blur();
    }
}, false);
$('input').keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      $(this).blur();
    }
});
```